# Show all history records for a particular Model.Id on Edit() View?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, razor, asp.net-mvc-partialview

In my Inventory Tracking program, I am attempting to show all the History Records for an Asset whenever someone opens up the Edit() View. My application has 2 relevant models `INV_Assets` and `INV_AssetsHistory`:

**INV_Assets**:

```
namespace InventoryTracker.Models
{
    [GridTable(PagingEnabled = true, PageSize = 30)]
    public class INV_Assets 
    {
        // Setting GridColumn Annotations allows you to use AutoGenerateColumns on view to auto create the Grid based on the model.


        public int Id { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<INV_AssetsHistory> AssetHistoryRecords { get; set; }

        public int Model_Id { get; set; }
        [ForeignKey("Model_Id")]
        public virtual INV_Models Model { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public int Manufacturer_Id { get; set; }
        [ForeignKey("Manufacturer_Id")]
        public virtual INV_Manufacturers Manufacturer { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public int Type_Id { get; set; }
        [ForeignKey("Type_Id")]
        public virtual INV_Types Type { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public int Location_Id { get; set; }
        [ForeignKey("Location_Id")]
        public virtual INV_Locations Location { get; set; }

        public int Vendor_Id { get; set; }
        [ForeignKey("Vendor_Id")]
        public virtual INV_Vendors Vendor { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public int Status_Id { get; set; }
        [ForeignKey("Status_Id")]
        public virtual INV_Statuses Status { get; set; }

        public string ip_address { get; set; }

        public string mac_address { get; set; }

        [DataType(DataType.MultilineText)]
        public string note { get; set; }
        public string owner { get; set; }

        //[DataType(DataType.Currency)]
        //[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString="{0:C}", ApplyFormatInEditMode=true)]
        [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:#,###0.00}", ApplyFormatInEditMode=true)]
        public decimal cost { get; set; }
        public string po_number { get; set; }

        [DataType(DataType.MultilineText)]
        public string description { get; set; }

        public int invoice_number{ get; set; }

        [Required]
        public string serial_number { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public string asset_tag_number { get; set; }

        [DataType(DataType.Date)]
        [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:yyyy-MM-dd}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
        public DateTime? acquired_date { get; set; }

        [DataType(DataType.Date)]
        [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:yyyy-MM-dd}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
        public DateTime? disposed_date { get; set; }

        [DataType(DataType.Date)]
        [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:yyyy-MM-dd}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
        public DateTime? verified_date { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [DataType(DataType.Date)]
        [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:yyyy-MM-dd}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
        public DateTime created_date { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public string created_by { get; set; }

        [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:yyyy-MM-dd}")]
        public DateTime? modified_date { get; set; }

        public string modified_by { get; set; }

        // Flag to specify if item is available? (Not signed out, not auctioned, recycled, etc.)
        //public bool available { get; set; }
    }
}
```

**INV_AssetsHistory**:

```
namespace InventoryTracker.Models
{
    public class INV_AssetsHistory
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public int AssetId { get; set; }
        //public virtual INV_Assets INV_Asset { get; set; }

        public int Model_Id { get; set; }
        [ForeignKey("Model_Id")]
        public virtual INV_Models Model { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public int Manufacturer_Id { get; set; }
        [ForeignKey("Manufacturer_Id")]
        public virtual INV_Manufacturers Manufacturer { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public int Type_Id { get; set; }
        [ForeignKey("Type_Id")]
        public virtual INV_Types Type { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public int Location_Id { get; set; }
        [ForeignKey("Location_Id")]
        public virtual INV_Locations Location { get; set; }

        public int Vendor_Id { get; set; }
        [ForeignKey("Vendor_Id")]
        public virtual INV_Vendors Vendor { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public int Status_Id { get; set; }
        [ForeignKey("Status_Id")]
        public virtual INV_Statuses Status { get; set; }

        public string ip_address { get; set; }

        public string mac_address { get; set; }

        [DataType(DataType.MultilineText)]
        public string note { get; set; }
        public string owner { get; set; }

        //[DataType(DataType.Currency)]
        //[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString="{0:C}", ApplyFormatInEditMode=true)]
        [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:#,###0.00}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
        public decimal cost { get; set; }
        public string po_number { get; set; }

        [DataType(DataType.MultilineText)]
        public string description { get; set; }

        public int invoice_number { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public string serial_number { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public string asset_tag_number { get; set; }

        [DataType(DataType.Date)]
        [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:yyyy-MM-dd}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
        public DateTime? acquired_date { get; set; }

        [DataType(DataType.Date)]
        [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:yyyy-MM-dd}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
        public DateTime? disposed_date { get; set; }

        [DataType(DataType.Date)]
        [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:yyyy-MM-dd}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
        public DateTime? verified_date { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [DataType(DataType.Date)]
        [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:yyyy-MM-dd}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
        public DateTime created_date { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public string created_by { get; set; }

        [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:yyyy-MM-dd}")]
        public DateTime? modified_date { get; set; }

        public string modified_by { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Now then, on my Edit() View I have attempted the following to get what I'm after:

**Attempt 1**:

I created a `_AssetHistoryRecordsPartial` view based upon my `INV_AssetsHistory` model using a `List` template. This is currently setup with the default code in my `Shared` Views folder.

```
@model IEnumerable<InventoryTracker.Models.INV_AssetsHistory>

<p>
    @Html.ActionLink("Create New", "Create")
</p>
<table class="table">
    <tr>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Location.location_dept)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Manufacturer.manufacturer_description)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Model.model_description)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Status.status_description)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Type.type_description)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Vendor.vendor_name)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.AssetId)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.ip_address)
        </th>

        ........

   </tr>

@foreach (var item in Model) {
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Location.location_dept)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Manufacturer.manufacturer_description)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Model.model_description)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Status.status_description)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Type.type_description)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Vendor.vendor_name)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.AssetId)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ip_address)
        </td>

        ................

    </tr>
}

</table>
```

*Edit() View*:

```
`@Html.Partial("_AssetHistoryRecordsPartial", Model.Id)`
```

When I run the application and load the Edit() view I receive the following flagging the above line of code for `@Html.Partial()`:

```
An exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in System.Web.Mvc.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'System.Int32', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1
```

As best I can tell, the error is saying that my `Partial` View is looking for an `IEnumerable<>` list for the Model, whereas I am passing in my main Model.Id (`INV_Assets`) Id from my Parent View?

**Attempt 2**:

Since I have a Collection of `INV_AssetHistory` defined on my `INV_Assets` Model (`public virtual ICollection<INV_AssetsHistory> AssetHistoryRecords { get; set; }`) I thought perhaps I could use this collection as the Model definition in a [GRIDMvc](https://gridmvc.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Quick%20start):

```
        <div class="assetList">
        @try
        {
            @Html.Grid(Model.AssetHistoryRecords).Columns(columns =>
            {
                columns.Add(o => o.Status.status_description).Titled("Status").RenderValueAs(o => o.Status.status_description).Sanitized(false).Encoded(false).Sortable(true).Filterable(true).SetWidth(20);
                columns.Add(o => o.Location.location_dept).Titled("Dept").RenderValueAs(o => o.Location.location_dept).SetWidth(20);
                columns.Add(o => o.Location.location_room).Titled("Room").RenderValueAs(o => o.Location.location_room).SetWidth(20);
                columns.Add(o => o.owner).Titled("Owner").RenderValueAs(o => o.owner).SetWidth(20);
                columns.Add(o => o.Type.type_description).Titled("Type").RenderValueAs(o => o.Type.type_description).SetWidth(20);
                columns.Add(o => o.Manufacturer.manufacturer_description).Titled("Manufacturer").RenderValueAs(o => o.Manufacturer.manufacturer_description).SetWidth(20);
                columns.Add(o => o.Model.model_description).Titled("Model").RenderValueAs(o => o.Model.model_description).SetWidth(20);
                columns.Add(o => o.Vendor.vendor_name).Titled("Vendor").RenderValueAs(o => o.Vendor.vendor_name).SetWidth(20);
                columns.Add(o => o.description).Titled("Desc").RenderValueAs(o => o.description).SetWidth(20);
                columns.Add(o => o.asset_tag_number).Titled("Asset Tag #").RenderValueAs(o => o.asset_tag_number).SetWidth(20);
                columns.Add(o => o.serial_number).Titled("Serial #").RenderValueAs(o => o.serial_number).SetWidth(20);
                columns.Add(o => o.ip_address).Titled("IP Addr").RenderValueAs(o => o.ip_address).SetWidth(20);
                columns.Add(o => o.mac_address).Titled("Mac Addr").RenderValueAs(o => o.mac_address).SetWidth(20);
                columns.Add(o => o.po_number).Titled("PO #").RenderValueAs(o => o.po_number).SetWidth(20);
                columns.Add(o => o.invoice_number).Titled("Inv. #").RenderValueAs(o => Convert.ToString(o.invoice_number)).SetWidth(20);
                columns.Add(o => o.cost).Titled("Cost").RenderValueAs(o => "$" + Convert.ToString(o.cost)).SetWidth(20);
                columns.Add(o => o.note).Titled("Note").RenderValueAs(o => o.note).SetWidth(20);
                columns.Add(o => o.acquired_date).Titled("Acq. Date").RenderValueAs(o => Convert.ToString(o.acquired_date)).SetWidth(20);
                columns.Add(o => o.disposed_date).Titled("Disp. Date").RenderValueAs(o => Convert.ToString(o.disposed_date)).SetWidth(20);
                columns.Add(o => o.verified_date).Titled("Ver. Date").RenderValueAs(o => Convert.ToString(o.verified_date)).SetWidth(20);
                columns.Add(o => o.created_date).Titled("Crtd. Date").RenderValueAs(o => Convert.ToString(o.created_date)).SetWidth(20);
                columns.Add(o => o.created_by).Titled("By").RenderValueAs(o => o.created_by).SetWidth(20);
                columns.Add(o => o.modified_date).Titled("Mod. Date").RenderValueAs(o => Convert.ToString(o.modified_date)).SetWidth(20);
                columns.Add(o => o.modified_by).Titled("By").RenderValueAs(o => o.modified_by).SetWidth(20);
            }).WithPaging(10).Sortable().Filterable().WithMultipleFilters();
        }
        catch (NullReferenceException ex)
        {
            return;
        }
    </div>
```

This however does nothing but render my columns with the data showing "There are no items to display". This I'm not understanding as I'm dealing with Asset 1 and I've ensured there is a record in `INV_AssetsHistory` pertaining to `INV_AssetsHistory.AssetId` == 1.

Can someone who perhaps has done something similar weigh in on how to go about this?

---

**Update**:

Using Murilo Amaru Gomes's suggestion I have the following:

**INV_Assets - Edit() View**:

```
    @{
        Html.RenderAction("AssetHistoryGrid", "INV_Assets", new { id = Model.Id });
    }
```

**INV_AssetsController**:

```
    public IQueryable<INV_AssetsHistory> GetHistoryByAssetId(int assetId)
    {
        var records = db.INV_AssetsHistory.Where(x => x.AssetId == assetId);
        return records;
    }

    public ActionResult AssetHistoryGrid(int id)
    {
        var list = GetHistoryByAssetId(id);
        return View("_AssetHistoryRecordsPartial", list);
    }
```

**Partial View - _AssetHistoryRecordsPartial**:

```
@model IEnumerable<InventoryTracker.Models.INV_AssetsHistory>
@using GridMvc.Html;
@using System.Collections.Generic;

<div class="assetList">
    @try
    {
        @Html.Grid(Model).Columns(columns =>
                {
                    columns.Add(o => o.Status.status_description).Titled("Status").RenderValueAs(o => o.Status.status_description).Sanitized(false).Encoded(false).Sortable(true).Filterable(true).SetWidth(20);
                    columns.Add(o => o.Location.location_dept).Titled("Dept").RenderValueAs(o => o.Location.location_dept).SetWidth(20);
                    columns.Add(o => o.Location.location_room).Titled("Room").RenderValueAs(o => o.Location.location_room).SetWidth(20);
                    columns.Add(o => o.owner).Titled("Owner").RenderValueAs(o => o.owner).SetWidth(20);
                    columns.Add(o => o.Type.type_description).Titled("Type").RenderValueAs(o => o.Type.type_description).SetWidth(20);
                    columns.Add(o => o.Manufacturer.manufacturer_description).Titled("Manufacturer").RenderValueAs(o => o.Manufacturer.manufacturer_description).SetWidth(20);
                    columns.Add(o => o.Model.model_description).Titled("Model").RenderValueAs(o => o.Model.model_description).SetWidth(20);
                    columns.Add(o => o.Vendor.vendor_name).Titled("Vendor").RenderValueAs(o => o.Vendor.vendor_name).SetWidth(20);
                    columns.Add(o => o.description).Titled("Desc").RenderValueAs(o => o.description).SetWidth(20);
                    columns.Add(o => o.asset_tag_number).Titled("Asset Tag #").RenderValueAs(o => o.asset_tag_number).SetWidth(20);
                    columns.Add(o => o.serial_number).Titled("Serial #").RenderValueAs(o => o.serial_number).SetWidth(20);
                    columns.Add(o => o.ip_address).Titled("IP Addr").RenderValueAs(o => o.ip_address).SetWidth(20);
                    columns.Add(o => o.mac_address).Titled("Mac Addr").RenderValueAs(o => o.mac_address).SetWidth(20);
                    columns.Add(o => o.po_number).Titled("PO #").RenderValueAs(o => o.po_number).SetWidth(20);
                    columns.Add(o => o.invoice_number).Titled("Inv. #").RenderValueAs(o => Convert.ToString(o.invoice_number)).SetWidth(20);
                    columns.Add(o => o.cost).Titled("Cost").RenderValueAs(o => "$" + Convert.ToString(o.cost)).SetWidth(20);
                    columns.Add(o => o.note).Titled("Note").RenderValueAs(o => o.note).SetWidth(20);
                    columns.Add(o => o.acquired_date).Titled("Acq. Date").RenderValueAs(o => Convert.ToString(o.acquired_date)).SetWidth(20);
                    columns.Add(o => o.disposed_date).Titled("Disp. Date").RenderValueAs(o => Convert.ToString(o.disposed_date)).SetWidth(20);
                    columns.Add(o => o.verified_date).Titled("Ver. Date").RenderValueAs(o => Convert.ToString(o.verified_date)).SetWidth(20);
                    columns.Add(o => o.created_date).Titled("Crtd. Date").RenderValueAs(o => Convert.ToString(o.created_date)).SetWidth(20);
                    columns.Add(o => o.created_by).Titled("By").RenderValueAs(o => o.created_by).SetWidth(20);
                    columns.Add(o => o.modified_date).Titled("Mod. Date").RenderValueAs(o => Convert.ToString(o.modified_date)).SetWidth(20);
                    columns.Add(o => o.modified_by).Titled("By").RenderValueAs(o => o.modified_by).SetWidth(20);
                }).WithPaging(10).Sortable().Filterable().WithMultipleFilters();
    }
    catch (NullReferenceException ex)
    {
        return;
    }
</div>
```

When I try to open the `Edit()` view, I receive the following:

```
An exception of type 'System.NotSupportedException' occurred in EntityFramework.SqlServer.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: The method 'Skip' is only supported for sorted input in LINQ to Entities. The method 'OrderBy' must be called before the method 'Skip'.
```

This error is flagged for `if (!Model.ItemsToDisplay.Any())` under `@helper RenderGridBody()` within the `_Grid.cshtml` which is part of the GRIDMvc package:

```
@helper RenderGridBody()
{
    if (!Model.ItemsToDisplay.Any())
    {
    <tr class="grid-empty-text">
        <td colspan="@Model.Columns.Count()">
            @Model.EmptyGridText
        </td>
    </tr>
    }
    else
    {
        foreach (object item in Model.ItemsToDisplay)
        {
    <tr class="grid-row @Model.GetRowCssClasses(item)">
        @foreach (IGridColumn column in Model.Columns)
        {
            @column.CellRenderer.Render(column, column.GetCell(item))
        }
    </tr>
        }
    }
}
```

Anyone have thoughts on this? I've never had an error like this before when using GRIDMvc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are passing the Model.Id to the UserControl. You should pass the items. Do you have them in the model? If so you can do @Html.Partial("_AssetHistoryRecordsPartial",  Model.Items), if you don´t you can use @{ Html.RenderAction("Action", "Some", new { id = Model.Id }); }, and in your controller you need

```
public class SomeController
{
    public ActionResult Grid(int id)
    {
          var list = // Logic code to fill the items
          return View("_AssetHistoryRecordsPartial", list);
    }
 }
```

Comment: Thanks for responding. Please see my EDIT above.

Comment: Change you query method to use any OrderBy db.INV_AssetsHistory.Where(x => x.AssetId == assetId).OrderBy(x => x.AnyProperty)